# Switching from apache to nginx - mod_rewrite issue

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-rewrite

I just switched my server over from apache2 to nginx and now I am having some issues with my .htaccess rewrites.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I have gathered that in order to make this work on Nginx, I will need to edit the Nginx server block. Would anyone be able to tell me how? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Look up [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that using try_files:

```
location (.*) {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

else you can use .htaccess to nginx converter http://winginx.com/en/htaccess, but as it is an automated process it will not be optimized:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
}
}
```

Comment: No no no, do _not_ use an .htaccess to nginx converter. It generates junk, as can be seen here.

Comment: I added informations about not optimal conversion